# asp:LinkButton in gridview to retreive audio file from folder to html audio so that it can play

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, audio, gridview

I have a webform that consist of

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audio" runat="server"></audio>
```

and

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">                    
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Date] FROM [tablename]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm so stuck at code behind. I want to play the audio file from folder by checking the date and path from database. I have something like the code below in vb

```
audio.Attributes("src") = "Audio/" 'I am unable to continue from here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the LinkButton from an `OnClick` to a `OnCommand`. That way you can send a `CommandArgument` with it.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command">LinkButton1</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in the `Command` method in code behind you can get the file name from the command argument an use it as the source for the player.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    audio.Attributes.Add("src", Server.MapPath("/Audio/" + fileName));
}
```

UPDATE

If the filename is always going to be the Text of the LinkButton, you can also cast the sender back to one and get the Text property.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
    audio.Attributes.Add("src", Server.MapPath("/Audio/" + lb.Text));
}
```

Comment: `audio.Attributes("src") = "Audio/" + Path.GetFileName(LinkButton2.Text)`

This code works if the linkbutton is kept outside the gridview. But I'm still confuse about linkbutton inside a gridview. 

The above code you provided is not working

Comment: What are you sending as a command argument? If the Text is the same as the filename, change it to `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'`

Comment: thanks, it works now after making some changes on source code and code behind.